# Gruvbox Airline Vim

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I am trying to get the gruvbox airline theme working for my vim status line.  I am using the plugged vim plugin manager and have added the gruvbox.vim airline theme to ~/.vim/plugged/vim-airline-themes/autoload/airline/themes.

**EDIT:** Realized I didn't source the 'vim-airline' plugin itself. I have added the following line to my .vimrc: 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

While the plugin is now working, the airline 'arrows' are not displaying.  The information in the status line is simply separated by boxes, not arrows.

**EDIT:**
I was able to get everything working properly (although a little hackish) by adding the following lines to my .vimrc:

```
" symbols section for unicode/airline symbols
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'

" airline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''
```

---

```
" Automatic installation for vim-plug IFF not currently installed
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
      \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
    autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif

" Plugins will be downloaded under the specified directory.
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Declare the list of plugins for vim-plug
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'junegunn/goyo.vim'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

"List ends here.  Plugins become visible to Vim after this call.
call plug#end()

syntax on
colorscheme gruvbox  " cool color scheme
let g:airline_theme='gruvbox.vim'
:set background=dark
let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark = 'hard'
let g:gruvbox_termcolors = 256

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4   " spaces when editing
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
retab

set number          " see numberlines

set showcmd         " see last command

set cursorline      " see cursorline

filetype indent on  " spec indent files, filetype tracking

set showmatch       " set parens to match each other

set incsearch           " search as characters are entered
set hlsearch            " highlight matches


filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

set laststatus=2
set t_Co=256
```

I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance for the help!

**EDIT:** Full working .vimrc with the Gruvbox airline theme looks like this:

```
" Automatic installation for vim-plug IFF not currently installed
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
      \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
    autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif

" Plugins will be downloaded under the specified directory.
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Declare the list of plugins for vim-plug
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'junegunn/goyo.vim'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

"List ends here.  Plugins become visible to Vim after this call.
call plug#end()

syntax on
colorscheme gruvbox  " cool color scheme
:let g:airline_theme='gruvbox'
:set background=dark
let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark = 'hard'
let g:gruvbox_termcolors = 256

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4   " spaces when editing
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
retab

set number          " see numberlines

set showcmd         " see last command

set cursorline      " see cursorline

filetype indent on  " spec indent files, filetype tracking

set showmatch       " set parens to match each other

set incsearch           " search as characters are entered
set hlsearch            " highlight matches


filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

set laststatus=2
set t_Co=256

" symbols section for unicode/airline symbols

" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'

" airline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''
```

Comment: I was able to get everything working properly (although a little hackish) by adding the following lines to my .vimrc:

Answer (score 3):

If you use `vim-plug` add to your `init.vim`:

```
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
```

Set `colorscheme gruvbox`

Save and quit. `:PlugInstall`, save and quit.

It should work. It comes with its own airline-theme natively and doesn't need the `vim-airline-theme` plugin.

See [repo for more info](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox).